# Scroll Case-s bug (mirror item)

Tags: baldurs-gate-2-enhanced

I have a total of 4 `Scroll Case`s. Let's call them number #1-#2-#3-#4.

Everything I do in #2 is **mirrored** in #3 (if I remove or add a scroll in #2, the same happens in #3).

It's like #2 and #3 are the same item somehow or they share the same item ID, something like that. This doesn't allow me to duplicate items tho.

This effectively reduces my `Scroll Case` count from 4 to 3, which kinda sucks (I got lots of scrolls to store).

Is this a know bug ? Is there a workaround to this ?

Comment: Did you give yourself the scroll cases using an editor, or did you acquire them normally? I had this issue with the Bag of Holding.

Comment: @Raj no editor, just the normal way. But I just found out the total amount of scroll cases in BG2 is 6 (as per https://baldursgate.fandom.com/wiki/Scroll_Case?so=search#Shadows_of_Amn) and I now have a total of 7. Maybe the item got duplicated somehow but I don't know how.